# Java AWT (y + height) is outside of Raster error while trying to get subimage

Tags: java, awt, game-development

So I have this method that loads an 1024x64 image and slices it in 8 equal parts.

```
@Override
public void loadAnimations() {
   idleAnimation = new LinkedList<>();
   BufferedImage image = Loader.getSprite(PLAYER);

   int idleAnimationLength = 8;
   for (int i = 0; i < idleAnimationLength; i++) {
      System.out.println(image);
      idleAnimation.add(image.getSubimage(i * 128, 64, 128, 64));
   }
}
```

The image is this one:
[image]

This is the output when the height (should be 64) is greater than 32.

```
BufferedImage@e6ea0c6: type = 6 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 32 numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@6a38e57f transparency = 3 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 1024 height = 64 #numDataElements 4 dataOff[0] = 3
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:1244)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(BufferedImage.java:1203)
    at org.victorpiles.engine.entity.player.Player.loadAnimations(Player.java:40)
    at org.victorpiles.engine.entity.player.Player.<init>(Player.java:19)
    at org.victorpiles.engine.Game.<init>(Game.java:13)
    at org.victorpiles.Main.main(Main.java:30)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The `System.out.println(image);` shows that the image width is 1024 and the height is 64. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `image.getSubimage(i * 128, 64, 128, 64)`, which grabs the pixel rows from 64 to 128 - but the image only has 64 rows.

Use `image.getSubimage(i * 128, 0, 128, 64)` instead.

See [Image.getSubimage() API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,int,int,int)).